# Why do I have to parse my json 2 times in an ajax request?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, parsing

I have a array with 188 json objects in it and I use an ajax request with `dataType: 'json'` to get(also parse) the data. But if I look at it in Chrome console i see it in a long string:
[Google Chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfvSC.png)

I want it to be this(don't know how to call this):[The right result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cq7Cz.png)

I get this result by a parsing function i made:

```
function parsing(parse) {
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; i++) {
        parse.push(JSON.parse(jsonArray[i].data));
    }
}
var jsonParsed = new Array();
parsing(jsonparsed);
```

My question is: "Why do i have to parse my array twice to get and use the data like `Temperatures[2]`?".

First time: `dataType: json`.

Second time: parsing function.

Comment: Please post any error message and expected results as formatted text into the question. Not everyone can see them. See [**Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) for more details.

Comment: It isn't code and there is no error but it's in Google Chrome console.

Comment: It doesn't only apply to code but any text that could be copied into the question. Anyway, I don't know what it is as I can't see images where I am, sorry.

Comment: Sorry that i can't paste it in but that's just the way it is.

Comment: I just forwarded the links to my phone and you can definitely copy 1 of the records as an example into the question directly from the console as the value you get and copy in a single record as an example from what you expect. You also can copy the error message you get in the first image "Unexpected Token". I can't do it for you as I can't copy the data from an image.

Comment: Why did you dislike my question? If you can't see the picture that it's your fault not mine.

Comment: @BianGoole true but it means that people can't help you. And also they have to make extra effort to view the picture. And also they can't easily re-use the text etc in any answer or comment to make a point. Lastly, it's the policy of the site - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**." An image is not within the question - the link could disappear, change etc over time.

Comment: @BianGoole if you don't like the site's policy then fine, it's your choice to ignore it, but you can't really justify getting annoyed with people if they point it out to you instead of answering your question. If you follow the policy when it's mentioned to you then we can get on with helping you. It's not difficult to copy and paste things out of the browser console.